# Spark client mode for mesos in Windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, docker, mesos

I started a Mesos master and slave in Docker.

Now I'm trying to run Spark in client mode in Mesos.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark in Mesos")
            .master("mesos://master:5050")
            .config("spark.executor.uri", "https://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz")
            .getOrCreate();
```

What I get is this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mesos in
>   java.library.path

I know that I have to set `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY`, but what should be this value on Windows and where can I download it?

In the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#client-mode) says about Linux and Mac OS X, nothing about Windows.